# searching k nearest neighbors in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to Python. I want to use numpy and sklearn to do `KNN`. However, there's a `nan` in my data. I set `dtype` of `genfromtxt` to `None` but the array will look like below:

```
[('ADT1_YEAST', 0.58, 0.61, 0.47, 0.13, 0.5, 0.0, 0.48, 0.22, 'MIT')
 ('ADT2_YEAST', 0.43, 0.67, 0.48, 0.27, 0.5, 0.0, 0.53, 0.22, 'MIT')
 ('ADT3_YEAST', 0.64, 0.62, 0.49, 0.15, 0.5, 0.0, 0.53, 0.22, 'MIT') ...,
 ('ZNRP_YEAST', 0.67, 0.57, 0.36, 0.19, 0.5, 0.0, 0.56, 0.22, 'ME2')
 ('ZUO1_YEAST', 0.43, 0.4, 0.6, 0.16, 0.5, 0.0, 0.53, 0.39, 'NUC')
 ('G6PD_YEAST', 0.65, 0.54, 0.54, 0.13, 0.5, 0.0, 0.53, 0.22, 'CYT')]
```

then, I will get `data type not understood` on `NearestNeighbors` function.

Here is my code:

```
npGem = np.genfromtxt('temp.data', dtype=None)
X = np.array(npGem)
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=5, algorithm='ball_tree').fit(X)
```

can anyone teach me how to make the list be read? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to give it a numpy.matrix where all of the elements are numberic.  Where are you getting this data from?

Comment: I will get data from my local disk.

Comment: What is the format in the file?

Comment: maybe like `ADT1_YEAST  0.58  0.61  0.47  0.13  0.5  0.0  0.48  0.22  MIT` in one line, it's not divided with `,` of every data in one line. So, I didn't use `delimiter`.

Comment: Is MIT a categorical variable? Or an outcome?  Or something else?

Comment: @aplassard Yes, it's a category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to get the data into a matrix properly.  I typically do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

features = [] # list of lists of the feature vairables.
classes  = [] # list of the target variables
for line in f:
    line = line.strip().split() # will split the line into pieces on any white spaces
    features.append(line[1:-1]) # or whatever indices your features are in
    classes.append(line[-1])    # or whatever index your target variable is in
classes  = np.array(classes)
features = np.array(features,dtype=np.float)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't think that I can just append they to different array and this way solve my problem.

Comment: Look in to the approach of @Emre.  That will provide some insights into how to handle categorical variables.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem, you're really asking how to encode the [categorical variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_variable) such that they can be properly interpreted by the nearest neighbors algorithm. You can do this with `sklearn` as explained in [4.2.4. Encoding categorical features](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features). On the other hand, if you have incomplete features, [4.2.6. Imputation of missing values](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#imputation-of-missing-values).